# How to handle event several layers deep, Java

Tags: java, exception, listener

I have a fairly complicated program that I have setup. In that program is a preferences window. One of the preferences is the server that the program is connected to. When the user changes that server, or adds another, the program needs to "restart" (dispose of and recreate the `main_window` class).

However I am lost on the best practices of how to do this. Here is the basic scenario in a stacked approach:

`main` Overall class, used for starting. Creates the main window class.

`main_window` JFrame that displays the data to the user

`prefs` JFrame that has many user settable options

`Server_Editor_Dialog_Box` JFrame that when the user hits OK, must restart the program

Anyways, My question is how do I notify main that something happened in ServerEditorDialogBox, and the program needs to restart. Should I throw an exception? Should I have a listener chain SEDB->prefs->main_window->main? Or should I do something entirely different?

Comment: The first thing that came to mind is the model-view-controller (MVC) architecture. You should have a controller class that acts as an actionlistener to the critical parts of the program that will need immediate action

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use an exception that will always be handled that way, but it *does* seem like the easiest solution.

The best solution for programming practice would be to use event listeners and have the listener/handler call a method to dispose and recreate the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

*'question is how do I notify "main" that something happened in "ServerEditorDialogBox", and the program needs to restart"*
==> Since "Server_Editor_Dialog_Box" and "main" would be executing in separate thread you need some sort of global messaging service because both threads have separate stack for execution. You could use a queue (java Collection) and **declare it as static** .  ServerEditorDialogBox could post the events to the queue and "main" can poll the queue and take action accordingly for events that it is intrusted in.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with an event bus that would allow me to propagate events to various controllers in a transparent way. I have used and I can recommend [Guava's EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). This allows you to structure your code better and decouple from the UI semantics that traditional Java listeners have.

The idea is that you subscribe a method in your Main class to a given event and you post it on the bus in your UI code (Server_Editor_Dialog_Box).